# What is the price for a new LCD screen in a Canon 550D ?

Tags: canon-550d, service-recommendation, lcd

I had an accident, I broke my LCD screen and I have no idea about the price of a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you want to replace it yourself, you should ask around in repair shops, for the cost of it and the replacement.

If you want the adventure, check on Alibaba, usually they sell wholesale, so you will have to ask around, and also getting speedy and quality service from China is tricky many times.

I suggest the first option above.

Comment: Thank you, i already spoke with sometechnicians. the cost more or less is about 50euros.